# CACHE MANIFEST não atualiza os arquivos

Tags: html5, cache

boa tarde, estou criando um website que deverá funcionar offline. minha ideia é que quando o usuário possuir conexão com internet as páginas do site deverão ser baixadas para o cache do navegador, e quando o usuário estiver offline as páginas deverão ser recuperadas do cache, até esta parte eu consegui fazer utilizando o CACHE MANIFEST porém mesmo estando online quando eu altero os meus arquivos continua sempre buscando do cache, forçando o usuário a limpar o cache para obter as novas alterações.
Alguém tem ideia de como posso fazer para "limpar o cache" apenas se houver alguma alteração entre os arquivos?

Comment: uma solução simples é salvar o arquivo `editado` com parâmetro `arquivo.ext?n=atualizacao_numero_xxx` onde xxx = numero diferente a cada atualização

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu li parte da documentação do CACHE MANIFEST e parece ter muitas configurações possíveis.
Mas o jeito mais preciso que conheço é manipulando diante as condições se você criar uma script assim dentro do cabeçalho do HTML poderá verificar se a página está online:

```
if(navigator.onLine == true){
    //tem conexao

}
```

Mas se for pra fazer algo preciso aconselho usar PHP:

```
<?php
$nc = "?".date("Ymdhis"); //exemplo 201802100720
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="javascript.js<?php echo $nc; ?>">
</head>
<body>
<img src="imagem.jpg<?php echo $nc; ?>" />
```